# onDraw method of child class of View is not calling when creating bridge module using SimpleViewManager

Tags: react-native

I am creating a custom view in android and to add this view on JS component in my react native project, I created a bridge module using ReactPackage method :

@Override

```
public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    List<ViewManager> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new MyCustomViewModule(reactContext));
    return list;
}
```

and passing object of custom child class of View in SimpleViewManager subclass (MyCustomViewModule) in method:

@Override

```
protected View createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
    return new CustomView(reactContext);
}
```

my problem is onDraw method is not calling of CustomView class. What should I do that onDraw method would call when this bridge module initiate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

onDraw in not calling because some props required when you would render your custom view in your JS component. You should pass the width and height as style props in your view like:

```
render() {
    <Your_module_view style={{width:100, height:100}}/>
}
```

Here you can pass any width and any height according to your view lay-outing.